# Как убрать меню текстового поля?

Tags: android

При долгом тапе по текстовому полю появляется попап со списком возможных действий (выбрать слово и т.д.) Как программно скрывать/показывать его?

П.С.: Вместо этого меню мне надо по долгому тапу, запускать свою обработку. На данный момент она запускается, но при этом еще появляется и этот попап.

Comment: а если мне надо будет свою обработку лонгтапа?

Comment: тогда сделаешь свой обработчик, OnLongClickListener, если не изменяет память

Comment: Вы должны указать системе что событие обработано:
    
     public boolean onLongClick(View v){     
     // Ваш код      
     return true;
}     
тогда контекстное меню не будет вызвано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упс, но ответы коллег выше в каментах - увы неверны.

В Андроиде при длинном тапе совершаются 2 независимых действия:

1. `OnCreateContextMenu()` - вызывается перед созданием контекстного меню
2. `OnLongClickListener()`

Меню, которое появляется это контекстное меню и оно отрабатывается вызовом `super.OnCreateContextMenu()` - если вы не будете его вызывать то и системное меню не появится.

Comment: По-поводу независимости не соглашусь       
onCreateContextMenu() - будет вызван системой только если View является long-clickable и обработчик OnLongClickListener не определён либо вернул false.       
Какое из этих условий "нарушить" зависит от желаемого результата

Comment: Уверены? Даже если `editText.setLongClickable(false);` контекстное меню будет вызвано :)

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, Вы правы, long-clickable здесь роли не играет.      
То у меня девайс приглючил - на эмулях действительно вызывается меню

Comment: @woesss ничего страшного бывает. Я эту фичу собственной мордой пропахал пару лет назад во всех ипостасях :)